# Run script when X window title changes

Tags: x11, i3, window-title

This script changes Firefox window titles from this pattern `[PageName] - Mozilla Firefox` to just `[pageName]`:

```bsh
pids=$(xdotool search --class "Firefox")
for pid in $pids; do
    name=$(xdotool getwindowname $pid)
    new_title=$(echo $name | sed "s/- Mozilla Firefox//")

    if [[ $name == "$name" ]] && [[ $name != "" ]]; then
      xdotool search --name "$name" set_window --name "$new_title"
    fi
done
```

Does anyone know if there is something like an *OnWindowChange* hook or another solution, that allows to run the script automatically, whenever a window title changes or a new window is created?

I'm using i3 window manager. Maybe there is a way to hook this up there?

Comment: try ` xprop -spy -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`

Comment: In the X11 protocol, it's called a PropertyNotify event. I don't think i3 can react to that but Devilspie probably can.